# How to instantiate SWRevealController programmatically with the value?

Tags: ios, swift

My goal is to instantiate SWRevealController Programmatically but seems like, but every time it would crash

Here's the code

```
    if let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "OnJobViewControllerID") as? OnJobViewController {

       var firstName = "Aegon"
       vc.driverName.text = firstName

         let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
        navController.setViewControllers([vc], animated:true)
        self.revealViewController().setFront(navController, animated: true)
    }
```

OnJobViewController is the ViewController

Always crash in here.

[image]

For clarity here is my storyboard

The main view Controller

[image]

SetFront segue

[image]

SetRear segue

[image]

Comment: does `self.revealViewController` has any value or it is nil at crashing?

Answer (score 0):

try this  :-

```
  let frontNavigationController:UINavigationController
let rearNavigationController:UINavigationController
let revealController = SWRevealViewController()
var mainRevealController = SWRevealViewController()
let objStoryboardMain                   = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", 
bundle: nil)

let sidebar = objStoryboardMain.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:  "viewSideMenu")as! SideMenuViewController

let homepage = objStoryboardMain.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewHomePage") as! HomePageViewController

frontNavigationController =  UINavigationController(rootViewController: homepage)
rearNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: sidebar)

revealController.frontViewController = frontNavigationController
revealController.rearViewController = rearNavigationController
revealController.delegate = self
mainRevealController  = revealController

self.window?.rootViewController = mainRevealController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

**Reference:-**

```
 https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController
```

Comment: error at this part `self.window?.rootViewController = mainRevealController` optional returns nil

Comment: can you please try this for push viewController    if let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "OnJobViewControllerID") as? OnJobViewController {

       var firstName = "Aegon"
       vc.driverName.text = firstName
        self.revealViewController().setFront(vc, animated: true)

    }

Comment: if you are setting RevealController programatically then use this or if you are using with segue then try to push using SWRevealViewControllerSeguePushController

Answer (score -1):

Hoping you are configuring your SWRevealViewController in the AppDelegate. 
Here is my implementation, hope it will help you. 
1> import SWRevealViewController:

```
import SWRevealViewController
```

2> implement the delegate:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, SWRevealViewControllerDelegate {
```

3> create an object off the revealeController:

```
var swRevealController: SWRevealViewController!
```

4> Now you can instantiate the SWRevealController such the following code with my own requirements.

```
func gotoPaymentVC(_ ride: Ride) {
    let acceptedVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PaymentVC") as! PaymentVC
    acceptedVC.ride = ride
    let rearViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LeftMenuVC") as! LeftMenuVC

    mainNavController  = UINavigationController(rootViewController: acceptedVC)
    mainNavController.isNavigationBarHidden = true
    let mainRevealController = SWRevealViewController(rearViewController: rearViewController, frontViewController: mainNavController)

    mainRevealController?.delegate = self
    self.swRevealController = mainRevealController
    self.window!.rootViewController = self.swRevealController
    self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

Comment: Error at this part   `self.window!.rootViewController = self.swRevealController`

Comment: Have you instantiated the window object of the AppDelegate??

if not please do it like this in the didFinishLaunch method of the AppDelegate class,  

    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

Comment: I did `var window: UIWindow?`

Comment: Sinus, its just an optional declaration of the object, please refer the updated comment above. You always need to instantiate an object before using it, else it ll return a nil as in your case.

Comment: Currently I'm using this revealViewController in my UIViewController. If I were to put it in appdelegate, how would I call goToPaymentVC in my UIViewController?

Comment: you can create object of the AppDelegate class such as: 

let kAppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

then you know you can call the method using this object:

kAppDelegate.goToPaymentVC

Comment: @sinusGob please mark this answer valid if it helped you solve your problem, if not then tell me the further problem you are facing.